# ['a', 'm', 'r', 'i', 't', ' ', 's', 'h', 'a', 'h', 'i'], After each ' ' in a word, would like to display the word. unable to display second word shahi

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, facebook-javascript-sdk

Would like to to display the word shahi as able to display first-word amrit after '', is there any way to display last word using code. help appricated.

```
function cap(cht){
         var part1 = [];
         var data = cht.split("")  //['a', 'm', 'r', 'i', 't', ' ', 's', 'h', 'a', 'h', 'i']
         for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
            if(data[i] === ' '){
                break;
            }
            part1.push(data[i]);
         }
         console.log(part1)
     }
     document.write(cap('amrit shahi'));
```

Output:
['a', 'm', 'r', 'i', 't']

likewise i would like to display shahi if i console log.

Comment: Any reason you don't just use `cht.split(' ')` to split it into words?

Comment: replace `break;` by `console.log(part1);` and reset the array

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: your function doesn't return anything, there is no need to display its result

Comment: i would to display separately, not only the one array

Comment: after '', break array and store in a separate variable

Comment: then you need to store each parts in an array and then return the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have two control structures:

1. The result array
2. A buffer to store sub-words

If you run into a space (and the buffer is not empty), add the buffer word to the results and clear it. Anything else is added to the buffer. If you reach the end and the buffer is not empty, add it to the results.

**Note:** There is no need to call split on the string. Characters can be accessed via `str[index]` or `str.charAt(index)`.

**Edit:** Added capitalization

```js
const capitalizeWord = (buffer) =>
  buffer[0].toUpperCase() + buffer.slice(1).join('');

const toTitleCase = (phrase) => {
  const results = [], buffer = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
    if (phrase[i] === ' ') {
      if (buffer.length) {
        results.push(capitalizeWord(buffer));
        buffer.splice(0, buffer.length);
      }
    } else {
      buffer.push(phrase[i]);
    }
  }
  if (buffer.length) {
    results.push(capitalizeWord(buffer));
  }
  return results.join(' ');
};

console.log(toTitleCase('amrit shahi'));
```

This can be rewritten as a switch for better understanding:

```js
const CHAR_SPACE = ' ';

const capitalizeWord = (buffer) =>
  buffer[0].toUpperCase() + buffer.slice(1).join('');
  
const toTitleCase = (phrase) => {
  const results = [], buffer = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
    switch (phrase[i]) {
      case CHAR_SPACE:
        if (buffer.length) {
          results.push(capitalizeWord(buffer));
          buffer.splice(0, buffer.length);
        }
        break;
      default:
        buffer.push(phrase[i]);
    }
  }
  if (buffer.length) {
    results.push(capitalizeWord(buffer));
  }
  return results.join(' ');
};

console.log(toTitleCase('amrit shahi'));
```

Comment: Please add code to capital letter A and S = Amrit Shahi as expected output

Answer (score 0):

```js
function cap(cht){
         var part1 = [];
         var data = cht.split("")  //['a', 'm', 'r', 'i', 't', ' ', 's', 'h', 'a', 'h', 'i']
         for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
            if(data[i] === ' '){
                break;
            }
            part1.push(data[i]);
         }
         return "Output: ["+part1.join('","')+"]"
     }
     document.write(cap('amrit shahi'));
```

Comment: i would be very happy if you correct my code

Comment: I edited answer with return and document.write

Comment: buddy please correct my code. it is es6 syntax i need it old one

Comment: Edit. You just must to add "return" at end of function

Comment: @AMRITSHAHI I'm curious. Why do you need it in ES5 ? Do you still need to support Internet Explorer ?

Comment: Thank you so much, after '', break array and store in a separate variable . still i need my answer. output like : input; 'amrit shahi', i need to store in array1 = ['a', 'm', 'r', 'i', 't'], and array2 = ['s', 'h', 'a', 'h', 'i'] from 'amrit shahi' string

Answer (score 0):

```
 function capital_letter(str) {
         str = str.split(" ");

         for (var i = 0, x = str.length; i < x; i++) {
            str[i] = str[i][0].toUpperCase() + str[i].substr(1);
         }

         return str.join(" ");
      }
      document.write(capital_letter('Amrit Shahi'))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).